# Which solution is better for getting random record set from db?

Tags: c#, sql-server, random

I want to get some random records from db. There is two solution for this :

1- Using `TABLESAMPLE` for getting data from db directly.

2- Write a method In my application for doing this. In this method we generate multiple random number and get data like this :

```
select * from db where ID = @RandomNumber
```

if this ID does not exist, I pass a new number.

Now which one has better performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation for TABESAMPLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx) you *shouldn't* use it if you "really want a sample of individual rows":

> If you really want a random sample of
>   individual rows, modify your query to
>   filter out rows randomly, instead of
>   using TABLESAMPLE. For example, the
>   following query uses the NEWID
>   function to return approximately one
>   percent of the rows of the
>   Sales.SalesOrderDetail  table:
>
> ```
>  SELECT  * 
>  FROM    Sales.SalesOrderDetail
>  WHERE   0.01 >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), SalesOrderID) & 0x7fffffff AS float)
>          / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
> ```
>
> The SalesOrderID column is included in
>   the CHECKSUM expression so that
>   NEWID() evaluates once per row to
>   achieve sampling on a per-row basis.
>   The expression `CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(),> SalesOrderID) & 0x7fffffff AS float / CAST(0x7fffffff AS int)` evaluates to a random float value between 0 and 1.

Either way, given the potentially endless number of requests you could make by passing in @RandomNumber (in theory the first 1000 requests you make might return nothing), the better approach is to limit the resultset on the server.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM db
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

the NewID function will generate UniqueIdentifier value and it will be random.
Source: [SQL to Select a random row from a database table](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm)

Comment: The question was "which method gives a better performance", so I would not recommend ORDER BY NEWID(). It requires assigning NEWID() to all rows, then sorting them all. This is expensive for large recordsets!

Answer (score 1):

I would use TABLESAMPLE, as its makes it very easy to generate sample data. I expect it would be more efficient as you only call one piece of SQL.

e.g.

```
USE AdventureWorks ;
GO
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person.Contact 
TABLESAMPLE (10 PERCENT)
```

In your other example, you will have to keep on calling `select * from db where ID = @RandomNumber` many times.

If you after individual rows then i would use another method, some form of random TOP 1 etc...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read a post about [various methods to get random row from table](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/09/16/my-thoughts-on-getting-random-row/). It's based on PostgreSQL, but I'm sure that 90% applies to SQL Server too.

Of course most flexible and best performing solution can be achieved by writing a stored procedure.

Cost (hence: best performance) of getting truly random sample depends on data (type of data, statistics and distribution, including sparseness).